# Swagger Ui hangs for api endpoint in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

My client api endpoint is not loading in swagger UI as shown in the image what I need to do? It always show loading icon when I click on any client controller api like get,post
Please post answer Thank You
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xpqx.png)

SwaggerConfig.groovy

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(metaData())
    }

    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Swagger Example")
                .description("\"Swagger configuration for application \"")
                .version("1.1.0")
                .license("Apache 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\"")
                .build()
    }
}
```

ClientController.groovy

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping('/client')
class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    ClientService clientService

    @GetMapping('/')
    ResponseEntity<List<Client>> getAllClients() {
        List<Client> clients = clientService.getAllClients()
        return new ResponseEntity<>(clients, HttpStatus.OK)
    }

    @GetMapping('/{clientId}')
    ResponseEntity<Client> getClientById(@PathVariable("clientId") Integer clientId) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(clientService.getClientById(clientId), HttpStatus.OK)
    }

    @PostMapping('/create')
    ResponseEntity<Client> createClient(@RequestBody Client client) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(clientService.addClient(client), HttpStatus.CREATED)
    }

    @PutMapping('/update/{clientId}')
    ResponseEntity<Client> updateClient(@PathVariable("clientId") Integer clientId, @RequestBody Client client) {
        clientService.updateClient(client, clientId)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(clientService.getClientById(clientId), HttpStatus.OK)
    }

    @DeleteMapping('/delete/{clientId}')
    ResponseEntity<Client> deleteClient(@PathVariable("clientId") Integer clientId) {
        clientService.deleteClientById(clientId)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please enter the config and controller codes here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MohammadJavad I have added the code